# How create XML output with crazy namespaces like (xmlns:json)

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have following input (no namespace):

**XML input**

```
   <book>
     <title>foo</title>
     <title>foo2</title>
    </book>
```

and I need to create with an **XSL transformation** the following ouput :

**XML output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:json="http://json.org/">
   <data json:force-array="true">
     <label>foo</label>
      <label>foo2</label>
   </data>
</root>
```

My current XSL stylesheet looks like :

**XSL Stylesheet **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:json="http://json.org/"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


<xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:element name="root" namespace="json">
        <xsl:attribute name="json">http://json.org/</xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:element name="data" namespace="json">
        <xsl:attribute name="json:force-array" namespace="json">true</xsl:attribute>

<xsl:for-each select="child::title">
    <xsl:element name="label"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>  
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This XSL gives the following output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="json" json="http://json.org/">
   <data xmlns:json="json" json:force-array="true">
      <label xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">foo</label>
      <label xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">foo2</label>
   </data>
</root>
```

**My three questions are :**

- How can I **remove the xmlns attribute** on  element ?
- How to create a **@xmlns:json** attribute ?
- How to remove **@xmlns:json="json"** attribute on  element ?

I'm using saxon9he parser.

Thanks in advance!
(I'm turning crazy!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

you specify a default namespace (XHTML, in this case) for all elements. With the simple input and output XML you have shown there seems to be no use for a default namespace.

Also note that this line from your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:attribute name="json">http://json.org/</xsl:attribute>
```

Does not denote a namespace. Rather, it is interpreted as an ordinary attribute named "json" with the URL as its value.

This stylesheet outputs the XML as you want it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:json="http://json.org/">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
  <xsl:element name="json:root">
     <xsl:element name="data">
        <xsl:attribute name="json:force-array">
           <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <xsl:element name="label">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This yields the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json:root xmlns:json="http://json.org/">
  <data json:force-array="true">
   <label>foo</label>
   <label>foo2</label>
  </data>
</json:root>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're working so hard. Using your example input, this simple stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/book">
    <root xmlns:json="http://json.org/">
        <data json:force-array="true">
            <xsl:for-each select="title">
                <label>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </label>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </data> 
    </root>  
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the specified output. Note that there are no namespace declarations in the `<stylesheet>` element, other than the required xsl.